# add a matrix to an array of matrices

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I had a matrix

```
A = tf.fill([2,2],2)
```

then an array of matrices

```
B = tf.fill([3,2,2],2)
```

how could I add the matrix A to all the matrices in B to produce

```
[
  [
    [4,4],
    [4,4]
  ],
  [
    [4,4],
    [4,4]
  ],
  [
    [4,4],
    [4,4]
  ]
]
```

then how could I sum each matrix in B to produce a vector like

```
[16,16,16]
```

?

I new to Tensorflow and my experience so far makes me feel there's an elegant way of doing this with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
A = tf.fill([2,2],2)
B = tf.fill([3,2,2],2)
A_B = tf.add(A, B)
sum_A_B = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_sum(A_B, axis=1), axis=1)
```